# "Incorrect string value" when inserting UUID into MySQL database

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have the following data class:

```java
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;  // = UUID.randomUUID()

    @Column(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    private Long accountId;

    ...
}
```

I am trying to save this object to our MySQL 5.7 database. However I am getting the following error:

```
    insert 
    into
        `
        task` (
            `account_id`, `created_at`, `task_status`, `task_type`, `id`
        ) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-08-15 08:57:57.943 TRACE 588 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2022-08-15 08:57:57.943 TRACE 588 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - [2022-08-15T08:57:57.943419Z]
2022-08-15 08:57:57.943 TRACE 588 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [RUNNING]
2022-08-15 08:57:57.943 TRACE 588 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [USER_IMPORT]
2022-08-15 08:57:57.944 TRACE 588 --- [           main] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [BINARY] - [c1808d19-f448-4d4f-9908-9e767d56b04f]
2022-08-15 08:57:57.945 ERROR 588 --- [           main] o.h.e.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch  : HHH000315: Exception executing batch [java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xC1\x80\x8D\x19\xF4H...' for column 'id' at row 1], SQL: insert into `task` (`account_id`, `created_at`, `task_status`, `task_type`, `id`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2022-08-15 08:57:57.945  WARN 588 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1366, SQLState: HY000
2022-08-15 08:57:57.945 ERROR 588 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect string value: '\xC1\x80\x8D\x19\xF4H...' for column 'id' at row 1
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.04 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.validity.entitlementui.service.TaskServiceIntegrationTest
saveTaskTest(com.validity.entitlementui.service.TaskServiceIntegrationTest)  Time elapsed: 0.036 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute batch; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute batch
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
```

Every other question I found about this error had issues with emoji or non-Latin characters but as you can see I'm just trying to insert a v4 UUID.

I am defining the `id` column as `VARCHAR(36)` and in the database options am setting the character set to `utf8mb4` (if that matters). Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe the value which you try to insert is inserted as binary UUID representation, not as string one? You may test - define the column as VARBINARY(36), insert, then investigate inserted value.

Comment: Ahhh that did it. Bizarre; we have another app using the exact same code and it works as written...must be something different between Liquibase/JPA/Spring/MySQL/whatever versions. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use a string/varchar representation in the table for the UUID column, with Hibernate 6 you can use:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.VARCHAR)
private UUID id;
```

Alternatively, as @Akina mentioned in his comment, changing the table column type to `VARBINARY(36)` also works, without needing the `@JdbcTypeCode` annotation.

Comment: This post, helped me. Thx